# Outer repeater property as data source of nested repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm struggling to find a solution for the following problem:
Today I have a repeater that show list of students.
Now I want to change the data source of the repeater from Student[] to Teacher[], and for each teacher to show all of his students.

example of the objects:

```
Teacher{
    string teacherName
    Student[] students
}

Student{
    string studentName
}
```

I understand that I need to use a nested repeater, but I don't understand how can I use the Students property (that comes from the outer repeater) as a data source for the inner repeater?

Is it possible?

Thanks

Pseudo code just for the big picture:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="Teachers">  
    <ItemTemplate>
        <Eval(teacherName)> 
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="<Eval(students)>">            
            <ItemTemplate>                                                
                <Eval(studentName)> 
            </ItemTemplate>           
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

UPDATE:
I managed to solve this using this answer:
[ASP.NET WebForms Nested Repeater With LINQ Group Data Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432618/asp-net-webforms-nested-repeater-with-linq-group-data-source)

Comment: eeeehm, when I got it right you just need to iterate the teachers in a loop. Within that loop you iterate the students for the current teacher in a second nested loop. Something like `foreach (Teacher t in teachers) { foreach(Student s in t.Students) { ... } }`.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Thank you for the answer. I'm looking for an asp.net solution using a repeater, not a C# solution.